# checklist-model and checklist-value not updating model or not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multi-select, checkboxlist

Below is the content of the HTML

```
<label ng-repeat="(index, item) in field.optionValue">
          <input type="checkbox" 
          checklist-model="formControlsValues[dbColumnName]"  
          checklist-value="item">{{field.optionName[index]}}
        </label>
```

**field.optionValue** and **field.optionName** is an Array

> field = { optionValue : ["1","2","3"], optionName : ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"] }

**checklist-model**, formControlsValues[dbColumnName] is a dynamic object model which is expected to populate the values when a checkbox is ticked/checked.
During rendering formControlsValues[dbColumnName] will be **$scope.formControlsValues.Village** or **$scope.formControlsValues.State** in the controller and is expected to populate is below mentioned format
**$scope.formControlsValues.Village** = **["2","1"]**

Comment: Can anyone please help me with a work around here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it. and it's working.

http://jsfiddle.net/fxsu6e79/1/

```
$scope.formControlsValues={
  State:[
     "1","3"
  ],
  Village:[
     "2","3"
  ]
};
```

is it ok?

Comment: Hi @fingerpich. First I wanna Thank you for working on this. 
The object should be 
$scope.field = { 
      optionValue : ["1","2","3"], 
      optionName : ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"], 
      dbColumnName : "State"
  }
Wherein I can track the Values  $scope.field.State

Comment: Also do I need to add "checklist-model" is a injector ?

Comment: you should add `checklist-model` module as a dependency in your Angular application and you don't need to inject it to the controller.

Comment: Thanks @fingerpich :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working code. I would like to point out you have to get numbers as numbers instead of strings(with double quotes) as you may lead to problems in future.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('checkList', ["checklist-model"]);

app.controller('checkListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.formControlsValues = {};
  $scope.field = { 
      optionValue : ["1","2","3"], 
      optionName : ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"],
      dbColumnName : "State"
  };
  
  $scope.dbColumns = ['State', 'Village'];
  $scope.formControlsValues = {
    Village : [],
    State : []
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="checkList">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="checklist-model.js@*" data-semver="0.0.1" src="http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/checklist-model.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="checkListCtrl">
      <h4>Checklist model</h4>
      <div>
        <label ng-repeat="(index, item) in field.optionValue">
            <input type="checkbox" 
            checklist-model="formControlsValues[field.dbColumnName]"  
            checklist-value="item">{{field.optionName[index]}}
        </label>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <select ng-model="field.dbColumnName" ng-options="d for d in dbColumns"></select>
      </div>
        <div>
          <label>Selected Villages: {{formControlsValues.Village}}</label>
        </div>
        <div>
         <label>Selected States: {{formControlsValues.State}}</label>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: +1 for " I would like to point out you have to get numbers as numbers instead of strings(with double quotes) as you may lead to problems in future.".  That was the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <label ng-repeat="(index,value) in field.optionValue">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="formControlsValues[field.dbColumnName]" checklist-value="value"> {{field.optionName[index]}}
  </label>
  values : {{ formControlsValues[dbColumnName]}}
</div>
```

Script

```
angular.module("DemoApp", ["checklist-model"])
.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.field = { 
      optionValue : ["1","2","3"], 
      optionName : ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"], 
      dbColumnName : "State" 

  }
  $scope.dbColumnName="State";
  $scope.formControlsValues={
      State:[]
  };
});
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/KarthikParameswaran/fxsu6e79/4/